# How does it gives constant output for the code below?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
        int i,a;
        printf("%d",printf("PRINT %d\t",scanf("%d %d",&i,&a)));
        return 0; 

}
```

This code is giving output

```
PRINT 2 8
```

I want to know how it is giving the same output for any number inputted. I'm a new user and sorry if I'm wrong somewhere. Thank You.

Comment: Where have you declared `i` and `a`?

Comment: I don't think it will even compile, since `i` and `a` are not defined.

Comment: When you fix the problems with the undeclared variables, read about [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) and see what they return.

Comment: It compiles and gives output "PRINT 2 8"

Comment: I have edited it again, I forgot the initialization.

Comment: So this is written in C++, but tagged as 'c'. Very confusing. Why?

Comment: and what about if you replace your `println(...)` with this `scanf("%d %d",&i,&a); printf("PRINT %d %d",i,a);` ?

Comment: @eliasah ,println(...) ? This is C not Java

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was working with Scala this afternoon I replied from my phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is the same as

```
int main() 
{
        int i,a;
        int p, s;
        s = scanf("%d %d",&i,&a);
        p = printf("PRINT %d\t",s)
        printf("%d", p);
        return 0; 

}
```

`scanf` returns the number of items assigned. In your case 2 variables, if successful.

Then you print the string "PRINT 2\t".

`printf` returns the number of characters written, 8 in this case.

And then you print that number, 8. Which means all the output of your program is "PRINT 2\t8"

Comment: Thanks a lot nos for your elaboration

Answer (score 3):

[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of items successfully read (in this case `2`).

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled.

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) returns the number of characters successfully printed (in this case, the inner printf returns `8`).

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
>
> If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a
>   negative number is returned.

Hence, elaborating the statement `printf("%d",printf("PRINT %d\t",scanf("%d %d",&i,&a)))`:

- Your innermost `scanf` would return `2`, since it reads 2 integers.
- Then your inner `printf` would become `printf("PRINT %d\t", 2)` and would write **8 characters** `PRINT 2\t`, hence returning `8`.
- Then your outer `printf` would become `printf("%d", 8)` and write `8`, making your combined output `PRINT 2 8`.

Comment: Please elaborate John Bupit. I'm a bit new to programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot John Bupit for your elaboration.